# «Не то... не то...» или «ни то... ни то...» — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы, частица-не, ни

"Не то дождь, не то снег"
или
"ни то дождь, ни то снег"?

Comment: Сочетание «ни то» пишется с «ни» в составе фразеологических выражений (ни то ни сё; ни то ни другое; ни то ни это) и без запятой.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ***не то дождь, не то снег***.

> **не то... не то**
> союз
> То же, что «то ли... то ли». <...>
> *На конце ленты **не то** красные, **не то** зеленые.* П. Бажов, Медной горы хозяйка. *Кузьме опять становится не по себе, в нем поднимается **не то** злость, **не то** робость.* В. Распутин, Деньги для Марии.

Источник: [academic.ru](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/453/%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE..._%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE)

[Из справочника под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=420): ***Не то** дождь моросит, **не то** снежная крупа сыплется.*

Answer (score 1):

**Не то… не то** — есть такой разделительный союз (см. [Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация. Раздел 9. Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении § 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=191)). Поэтому верно:

***Не то** дождь, **не то** снег.*

Аналогичные примеры встречаются в литературе, приведу несколько для наглядности.

*Уже при въезде во двор Кожемякин испуганно почувствовал, что дома случилось неладное; Шакир, ещё более пожелтевший и высохший, бросился к нему, взвизгивая и всхлипывая, **не то** плача, **не то** смеясь, завертелся, схватил за руку, торопливо ввёл в дом, прихлопнул дверь и встал перед ним, вытянув изрезанную морщинами шею, захлёбываясь словами: <...>* [Горький М., "Жизнь Матвея Кожемякина", 1911]

***Не то** страшно, **не то** неприятно ей было.* [Толстой Л., "Поликушка", 1862]

*И, скажу вам, засуха стояла тогда такая, что никто и не запомнит; в воздухе **не то** дым, **не то** туман, пахнет гарью, мгла, солнце, как ядро раскаленное, а что пыли — не прочихнешь!* [Тургенев И., "Собака", 1870]